# Converting user input from html table to JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am able to convert a pre populated table with data to `JSON` object with jQuery. Here is the code:

```
var header = $('table thead tr th').map(function () {
return $(this).text();
});

var tableObj = $('table tbody tr').map(function (i) {
    var row = {};
    $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
        var rowName = header[i];
        row[rowName] = $(this).text();
    });
    return row;
}).get();

JSON.stringify(tableObj);
```

And the html table is like this:

```
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Job</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>jason</td>
            <td>jason@example.com</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ted</td>
            <td>ted@example.com</td>
            <td>Bear</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Now my task is to actually handle empty table with user inputs. When user load the page, the table is empty with no value, after the user entered the input and click submit, I want to convert the user input data into `JSON` object and pass it back to back-end.

I am trying to make it happen by warp the `table` into a `form`, and add `<input>` tag in each `<td>`, something like this:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I try to use the `.submit()` method from jQuery to make it work but I am getting syntax errors:

```
$('form').submit(
var header = $('table thead tr th').map(function () {
return $(this).text();
});

var tableObj = $('table tbody tr').map(function (i) {
    var row = {};
    $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
        var rowName = header[i];
        row[rowName] = $(this).text();
    });
    return row;
}).get();

JSON.stringify(tableObj);
);
```

How should I change my code to make it work?

Comment: Have you considered using something like DataTables (http://www.datatables.net)? Automatically builds tables using a JSON object and allows for a lot more functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening bacause there is no text in the `td`. You need to find the value of the input.

1) You need to get the `input` in the `td`

2) You need to get the [value of the input](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Also try to look at the [editable div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Try this:

```
row[rowName] = $(this).find('input').val();
```

Comment: Also he's not correctly defining the `submit()` handler. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8uhdhge6/